# How to make this template for an article?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, affiliation

I want to separate the address of the authors with a box where I will put the abstract according to the graphic template below. Right alignment is important.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to Make Two Different Headers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464000/5764)

Comment: I want separate \maketitle? In this post.

Comment: That's right. The idea is this, but it stays in footnote I want want soon after the abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to put `\maketitle` and the abstract within a minipage, then borrowing from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135652/173134) for the styling of the affiliation and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18497/173134) for the proper centering of the minipage.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\and{%
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\else\@ctrerr\fi}}
\makeatother
\title{My Title}
\author{Luke Skywalker\thanks{Some Affiliation} \and Mara Jade\thanks{Some Other Affiliation}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\kant[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{minipage}}
\section{Introduction}
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I want to use numbers instead of letters in "a Some Affiliation" for "1 Some Affiliation"?

Comment: A simple replace of the letters in the `\def\@fnsymbol` line, it picks from there.